# Help me identify this plant that has taken over an abandoned garden

Tags: identification

They've taken over an abandoned garden nearby and look positively alien to me. I've never seen a plant grow this kind of flowers or... fruits, since they look like fruits.

[image]

Could anyone help me identify it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Phytolacca, common name Pokeweed - I think it might be Phytolacca polyandra, rather than P. americana, the latter having red stems from which the flowers spring. Also called Chinese Pokeweed. Berries are toxic so if there are young children about, you might want to get rid of these https://frustratedgardener.com/2014/08/29/daily-flower-candy-phytolacca-polyandra/

Comment: They are indeed alien then — I'm in Eastern Europe. What an interesting find, thank you!

Comment: Check out 'carmaz' - that, or so I'm told, is the Romanian common name for Phytolacca... if it has a common name in your language, that probably means it does grow there, even though its not native... though common names vary from area to area, as well as country to country.